# Circle Using different Buttons ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Actually i had simple image with these pictures, i just get these 3 images through slicing and put on buttons.
I have 3 Buttons with images on it, images are in different shapes. These 3 images will make a circle as shown below

[image]
and they are overlapped as shown below,
[image]

Now when screen changes buttons should also changes according to screen keeping their shape same as it is. How to implement this. As these buttons are overlapping but i have handles this using a library which make button clickable only on non-transparent part. 
I have set constraints but due to overlapping they are not showing what i wan.
This is what am getting [image]

Comment: screen change means swing the circle something like that?

Comment: *"they are not showing what i want"* --- well, you need to show ***us*** what you want, if you're hoping for some help.

Comment: I'd say that your images need to be cropped again, but smartly. I'd add extra transparent space around them at some sides. Explain to your designer the issue and it should crop them correctly. The easiest way of all (if your thrid party lib can allow button detection only on non transparent part), is to have the same size (the whole 3 buttons togother size), and keep only one non-transparent for each one.

Comment: My library is handling this transparent part only,

Answer (score 0):

If you are still trying to get this working...

Create your 3 images all at the same size, then lay them exactly on top of each other. In this image, the pink areas are the transparent / alpha areas of the images:

[image]

and this is how it looks when they are layered together:

[image]